# Azure CLI or PowerShell command to create new version of a certificate in keyvault

Tags: azure, azure-powershell, azure-keyvault, azure-cli

I want to create a new version of a certificate in keyvaule using command line (az cli or powershell). Does anyone know how to do that?

[image: k]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To create a new version, just use [`Add-AzKeyVaultCertificate`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.keyvault/add-azkeyvaultcertificate?view=azps-4.6.1) powershell command, specify the name of the certificate, then it will create a new version.

Sample:

```
$Policy = New-AzKeyVaultCertificatePolicy -SecretContentType "application/x-pkcs12" -SubjectName "CN=contoso.com" -IssuerName "Self" -ValidityInMonths 6 -ReuseKeyOnRenewal
Add-AzKeyVaultCertificate -VaultName "keyvaultname" -Name "joycer" -CertificatePolicy $Policy
```

[image]

For Azure CLI, this command [`az keyvault certificate create`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/keyvault/certificate?view=azure-cli-latest#az-keyvault-certificate-create) should also work.

```
az keyvault certificate create --name
                               --policy
                               --vault-name
                               [--disabled {false, true}]
                               [--subscription]
                               [--tags]
                               [--validity]
```

Comment: thanks Joy, yes, the command "az keyvault certificate create" is the correct command