# Make Terraform azurerm_key_vault_certificate module create a new version of Key Vault Certificate

Tags: azure, azure-keyvault, lets-encrypt, terraform-provider-azure

newbie here to don't punch too hard please.

The big picture goal is: automating the process of provisioning a new SSL cert from Lets encrypt, storing the cert in Azure key vault and then propagating it to a bunch of azure VMs. We have a solution in place but of course it was created by people who are no longer with the organization and now we're trying to improve it to work for our scenario. The current problem is: terraform is trying to delete an existing cert from Azure key vault and then create a new one with the same name. Of course, soft delete and purge protection are both enabled and (!) it's a group policy imposed by AAD so they can't be disabled to create a new vault without them. I've read [here](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-azurerm/issues/10658) that it's possible to work around the issue using terraform's null resource but I know nothing about it to be able to use it. Does anyone have an idea how exactly this could be achieved? Please feel free to ask further questions, I'll answer what I can. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To use null_resource first, we must define the null_resource provider in our `main.tf` file.See [Terraform null provider and null_resource explained | by Jack Roper | FAUN Publication](https://faun.pub/terraform-null-provider-and-null-resource-explained-6a8d674cad63#:%7E:text=The%20Terraform%20null_resource%20is%20commonly%20used%20to%20run,is%20not%20supported%20in%20the%20azurerm%20Terraform%20provider.)

```
required_providers {
    azurerm = {
        source  = "hashicorp/azurerm"
        version = "~> 2.43"
    }
    null = {
        version = "~> 3.0.0"
    }
}
```

- Then if you have defined the resources keyvault , certificate..

  ```
  resource "azurerm_key_vault" "kv" {
     name                       = "ansumankeyvault01"
     location                   = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.location
     resource_group_name        = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
    ....
       tenant_id    = 

   }

   resource "azurerm_key_vault_certificate" "example" {
     name         = "generated-cert"
     key_vault_id = azurerm_key_vault.example.id

     certificate_policy {
    ...
       }

   key_properties {
     ...
   }

   lifetime_action {
     action {
       action_type = "AutoRenew"
     }

     trigger {
       days_before_expiry = 30
     }
    ...
   }
  ```
- Please check the workaround in
  [terraform-provider-azurerm/issues](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-azurerm/issues/10658#issuecomment-1067110414) as you mentioned.

Refer : [***null_resource*** | Resources | hashicorp/null | Terraform Registry](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/null/latest/docs/resources/resource)   /

**Powershell  using local-exec provisioner :**

```
resource "null_resource" "script" {
   
provisioner "local-exec" {
   command = 
“Add-AzKeyVaultCertificate -VaultName  ${azurerm_key_vault.kv.name}
 -Name ${ azurerm_key_vault_certificate.example.anme } -CertificatePolicy  ${ azurerm_key_vault_certificate.example.certificate_policy}”
    
  interpreter = ["powershell", "-Command"]
 
 depends_on = [azurerm_key_vault_certificate.example]

   }
}
```

or using az cli commands.
resource "null_resource" "nullrsrc" {

```
provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = " az keyvault certificate create --name
                               --policy   ${ azurerm_key_vault_certificate.example.certificate_policy}
                               --vault-name  ${azurerm_key_vault.kv.name}
Depends_on = [azurerm_key_vault_certificate.example]

  }

  }
```

Or you can create a powershell command script to reference

```
resource "null_resource" "create_sql_user" {

  provisioner "local-exec" {
    
command     = ".'${path.module}\\scripts\\update_cert_version.ps1' "
    interpreter = ["pwsh", "-Command"]
  }
  depends_on = [azurerm_key_vault_certificate.example]
}
```

**References**

1. [Azure CLI or PowerShell command to create new version of a
   certificate in keyvault - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63678349/azure-cli-or-powershell-command-to-create-new-version-of-a-certificate-in-keyvau)
2. [Execute AZ CLI commands using local-exec provisioner · Issue #1046 ·
   hashicorp/terraform-provider-azurerm · GitHub](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-azurerm/issues/1046)